# Failed to assign an array returned by a python script to a variable in VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

When I execute this python script on bash, this is what I receive, which is all good.

`ans=$(python getIndividualCurrentPrice.py 1113 0001 0293 0004 1972 0005 0003 0941)`

`echo $ans
[u'68.00', u'110.90', u'18.60', u'51.80', u'25.50', u'73.15', u'15.88', u'110.10']`

However, when I tried to execute this python script *through* VBA, this is what I did in VBA:

`RetVal = Shell("C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\getIndividualCurrentPrice.py 1113 0001 0293 0004 1972 0005 0003 0941" )`

`MsgBox(RetVal)`

`10980`

**UPDATE:**
I managed to execute the python script in VBA without any error now, **but the returned value is** `10980` a random number, which doesn't make sense.  The interesting thing is that I could see that a python.exe was launched and the correct results was shown in there. But the returned results was never stored in the VBA variable `RetVal`. **What is going wrong in here ? **

**Sidenote:** I tried `MsgBox(Shell("echo $HOME"))` but I got a value `26988`, which made no sense at all. How do I get around this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Shell() returns something like a process ID -- not the standard output.

I'm not sure how you would do this in pure VBA. If you are on a Windows machine, you could use VBScript's Windows Script Host. Just make sure that you include a reference to the Windows Script Host Object Model in your VBA project (under the tools menu item in the VBE if you haven't done this sort of thing). The following code illustrates how you can capture the output of standard output to a string variable. I wrote a simple .py script file to compute factorials. Then:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As New WshShell
    Dim exec As WshExec
    Dim output As String
    Set exec = ws.exec("python C:/programs/factorial.py 10")
    output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll
    MsgBox output 'prints 3628800
End Sub
```